# Assigning value to a * character within a hash

Tags: perl, hash

Using the following section of code I ordinarily split a mixed string-integer field (e.g. 45A34C) and tally up instances of each letter (designated by the integer proceeding it) according to a set of rules stored in %r. This works fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @F; $F[5] = '*';
my @ar = split(/([ABCD])/, $F[5]);
my %r = (A => 1, B => 1, C => 0, D => 1, '*' => 0);
my $s = 0;
my $op;
my $n;
$s += $n * $r{$op} while ($n,$op) = splice @ar,0,4;
```

However, in some instances, `$F[5]` contains nothing but an asterisk - a literal `*` character. Any line containing this returns these warnings:

```
Use of uninitialized value $op in hash element at b.pl line 10.
Use of uninitialized value in multiplication (*) at b.pl line 10.
Argument "*" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at b.pl line 10.
```

Which is expected given that `*` is not assigned a number. I've attempted to assign the character a number in the hash, but am unable to figure out the correct syntax. I've tried:

```
my %r = (A => 1,B => 1,C => 0,D => 1, * => 0);
my %r = (A => 1,B => 1,C => 0,D => 1, \* => 0);
```

But the warnings remain. What is the correct way to assign a value to a special character and why can * not be handled like 'A' can?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my %r = (A => 1, B => 1, C => 0, D => 1, '*' => 0);
```

`=>` "autoquotes" its LHS when it's an identifier, but it need not be an identifier; it can be any expression. (In fact, you don't even need to use `=>`, which just a fancy comma (`,`).)

---

But that doesn't fix your problem. `@ar` only contains `*`, so `$n` is `*` and `$op` is undefined. `@ar` needs to have at least two values for that code to work. So let's explicitly look for values that make sense.

```
my %r = (A => 1, B => 1, C => 0, D => 1 );

my $s = 0;
while ($F[5] =~ /(\d+)([ABCD])/g) {
   my $n  = $1;
   my $op = $2;
   $s += $n * $r{$op};
}
```

---

By the way,

`* => 0` is a weird way to write `*= > 0`, which means "is glob `*=` numerically greater than zero".

`\* => 0` is a weird way to write `\*= > 0`, which means "is the address of glob `*=` numerically greater than zero".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For some reason,  when using `'*' => 0`, the same warnings are still returned so the problem may be something else other than what I thought it was. If I add the * into the split, the warning becomes: `Argument "" isn't numeric in multiplication (*) at line 36, <IN> line 26.` which, i'm guessing, is because i'm trying to split a field that contains nothing but * by * and creating an empty string?

Comment: Well, I answered the question you asked. It seems you have a second problem. I'll update shortly.

Comment: Yes - my apologies for that. I tested all things I could think of and was quite sure it was simply due to the non-assignment of *.

Comment: This now returns the warning: `Use of uninitialized value $n in multiplication (*) b.pl line 37, <IN> line 22.` for all input lines whether they contain * or not. What is causing that?

Comment: Would it be better to simply append a value onto * when `@ar = '*'` such that `$op` is no longer empty? e.g. `@ar = 1*`?

Comment: oh, you wanted to multiply by the number. Oops! Tired. Updated answer.

Comment: Now with missing `g`!